# Symfony2 cookbook load user from DB tutorial - repository class missing

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to follow the Symfony2 cookbook tutorial for loading users from a DB.

The tutorial assumes you have a ACME/UserBundle and my installation doesn't, but I just assumed I could make my own (it's not like a plugin-packade I need to download somewhere right?).

I created a bundle UserBundle and copy-pasted the code from the tutorial's entity User (first code box [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html)).

This line seems to break things for me:

```
  @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Mycompany\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
```

The error message I get is:

```
Fatal error: Class 'mycompany\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository' not
found in /var/www/mycompany/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php
on line 578
```

So I either assume I couldn't just create my own UserBundle (strange since I thought this was a tutorial on how to do it, not how to install a plugin that does it), or they assumed I knew that I somehow needed to register the entity among entityRepositories somehow?

I will be most grateful if anyone more senior in symfony would enlighten me on this. I truly love all that I have learned about Symfony2 so far, but I am a bit of a slow learner here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you dont have a user repository class, this is seperate to the user entity class.  It goes in the entity folder but would be UserRepository.php and look something like:

```
namespace Mycompany\UserBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException;

// Implements userproviderinterface so we can use the user entity for authentication
// Extends entityrepository so that it gets methods definded there
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserProviderInterface {

  //  This function is called when a user tries to login, the below lets the user use their username or email for username
  public function loadUserByUsername($username) {
    $user = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->select('u, r')
            ->leftJoin('u.roles', 'r')
            ->where('u.username = :username OR u.email = :username')
            ->setParameter('username', $username)
            ->getQuery();
    try {
      $user = $user->getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException $exc) {
      throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('Unable to find an active UserBundle:User object identified by %s', $username));
    }
    return $user;
  }
  // 
  public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user) {
    $class = get_class($user);
    if (!$this->supportsClass($class))
      throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('instances of class %s are not supported', $class));
    return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
  }

  public function supportsClass($class) {
    return $this->getEntityName() === $class || is_subclass_of($class, $this->getEntityName());
  }

}
```

This class is available futher down the tutorial you are doing http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html

Comment: true, but the way the tutorial reads, this class seems optional to the userBundle to work, they have it as a way of logging in with either username or email, so the whole thing shouldn't break without it...

Comment: Thats kind of true but because you declare the repository in the entity class with the line you mention in your question, you have to have one.  You don't have to prepopulate it like my answer if you don't extend the userproviderinterface

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to generate the correct class using the `doctrine:generate:entities` command. [(Documented in the book.)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes)

I think your command should look like this:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities User
```

Comment: Aha, I thought that command just auto-generated some functions for the entity, I didn't understand you need to run that to actually create the entity class from off your code.